# How to add title to Polygon using react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to draw specific polygons in MapView, but I'm not sure how to add title to Polygon.

I tried to search official documentation, but only Marker has title property, so I'm not sure if it's supported.

Marker can be used something like this

```
<Marker
    coordinate={latittude: x, longitude: y}
    title="I am Marker"
/>
```

so is it possible to add title property to Polygon like this:

```
<Polygon
    coordinates=[{latittude: x, longitude: y},...]
    title="I am Polygon"
/>
```

???[Expecting something like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heygx.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have any other option but you can use marker which works pretty nice.

```
<MapView.Marker key={`${key}Marker`} coordinate={center} anchor={centerAnchor} tracksViewChanges={false}>
    <Text key={`${key}Text`} style={styles.clusterText}>
        {data.properties.n}
    </Text>
</MapView.Marker>
```

don't forget the tracksViewChanges={false} or the map will go crazy for many markers and put a huge load on the cpu

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, I know this is late but here's what I did. I also didn't know if react native maps have that method right now. So for alternative, I used `Marker` as title. And used this [function](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/1325) from github to get the center of polygon.

```
center_polygon(coordinates) {
    let x = coordinates.map(c => c.latitude);
    let y = coordinates.map(c => c.longitude);

    let minX = Math.min.apply(null, x);
    let maxX = Math.max.apply(null, x);

    let minY = Math.min.apply(null, y);
    let maxY = Math.max.apply(null, y);

    return {
      latitude: (minX + maxX) / 2,
      longitude: (minY + maxY) / 2
    };
  }
```

Polygon

```
return (
        <View>
          <Marker 
            coordinate={polygon_center}  
          >
            <Text note style={{color:"#000", fontSize: 9}}>
              {name}
            </Text>
          </Marker>
          <Polygon
            key={index}
            coordinates={fixed_coordinates}
            fillColor={this.hexToRgbA(color, 0.4)}
            strokeColor={color}
            strokeWidth={3}
          >

          </Polygon>
        </View>
      );
```

Comment: Yes. I did that, but I faced another problem. If you have polygon with L shape, Marker is out of the polygon. But I stopped using Google Maps and start using react-map-gl. It's got much better performance and there is a lot of ways of using it entirely free. Anyway thank you for suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Proper complete solution for adding any component over polygon in center.**
[image: Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 12 - 2022-09-30 at 01 06 50]

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  InteractionManager,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import MapView, {Marker, Polygon} from 'react-native-maps';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {COLOR_PLOT_BORDER} from '../../utils/colors';

let polygonsCoordinates = [
  [
    {latitude: 42.9348443, longitude: -72.287181},
    {latitude: 42.9345929, longitude: -72.2832328},
    {latitude: 42.9335415, longitude: -72.2834162},
    {latitude: 42.9335572, longitude: -72.2852186},
    {latitude: 42.9336671, longitude: -72.2869996},
    {latitude: 42.934704, longitude: -72.2871498},
  ],
  [
    {latitude: 42.9345437, longitude: -72.2811199},
    {latitude: 42.9347204, longitude: -72.2795911},
    {latitude: 42.9343119, longitude: -72.2792585},
    {latitude: 42.9341077, longitude: -72.2810394},
    {latitude: 42.9345358, longitude: -72.2811146},
  ],
  [
    {latitude: 42.9329962, longitude: -72.2825093},
    {latitude: 42.9333065, longitude: -72.2804494},
    {latitude: 42.9322775, longitude: -72.2801382},
    {latitude: 42.931979, longitude: -72.2824235},
    {latitude: 42.9329726, longitude: -72.2824932},
  ],
];

export default function MapPlots() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({});
  const [polygonCenters, setPolygonCenters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      goToLocation();
      getCenterOfAllPolygon();
    });
  }, []);

  const getCenterOfAllPolygon = () => {
    let centers = [];
    polygonsCoordinates.map((v, i) => {
      let c = getCenterPolygon(v);
      centers.push(c);
    });
    setPolygonCenters(centers);
    console.log('centers', centers);
  };

  const keeneRegion = {
    latitude: 42.9329962,
    longitude: -72.2825093,
    latitudeDelta: 0.02,
    longitudeDelta: 0.02,
  };
  const goToLocation = () => {
    //complete this animation in 5 seconds
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion(keeneRegion, 1 * 1000);
  };

  let getCenterPolygon = coordinates => {
    let x = coordinates.map(c => c.latitude);
    let y = coordinates.map(c => c.longitude);

    let minX = Math.min.apply(null, x);
    let maxX = Math.max.apply(null, x);

    let minY = Math.min.apply(null, y);
    let maxY = Math.max.apply(null, y);

    console.log('adsasdad', minX, maxX, minY, maxY);

    return {
      latitude: (minX + maxX) / 2,
      longitude: (minY + maxY) / 2,
    };
  };

  const onPressPolygon = coordinates => {
    let newCoordinates = getCenterPolygon(coordinates);
    const goToRegion = {
      ...newCoordinates,
      latitudeDelta: 0.01,
      longitudeDelta: 0.01,
    };
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion(goToRegion, 1 * 1000);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 0, // This the position data
          longitude: 0, // This is also position data
          latitudeDelta: 200,
          longitudeDelta: 1,
        }}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        onRegionChangeComplete={r => setRegion(r)}>
        {polygonsCoordinates.map((polygon, i) => (
          <View key={i}>
            <Polygon
              coordinates={polygon}
              strokeColor={COLOR_PLOT_BORDER} // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
              fillColor={i === 0 ? 'blue' : i === 2 ? 'green' : 'yellow'}
              strokeWidth={0.3}
              tappable
              geodesic
              onPress={() => onPressPolygon(polygon)}
            />
            <Marker
              anchor={{x: 0.5, y: 0.5}}
              centerOffset={{x: 0.5, y: 0.5}}
              zIndex={10}
              coordinate={polygonCenters[i]}>
              <Text note style={{color: '#000', fontSize: 15}}>
                1001
              </Text>
            </Marker>
          </View>
        ))}
      </MapView>
      <Button onPress={() => goToLocation()} title="Go to Current Location" />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Current latitude{region.latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Current longitude{region.longitude}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
});
```